# How to get specific values of objects inside an arraylist of the objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an `ArrayList` of `Shape`s, a class I created. The ArrayList contains different kinds of shapes. I also created some classes of other shapes (circle, rectangle, etc).

I used scanner so a user can type width, height, etc., of a shape he chose and that got saved inside the arraylist which contains all the shapes he creates.

How can I get the width for example, of all the shapes? I found solutions with hashMaps but is there a simpler solution?

I need to do arithmetic actions with them.

Comment: show us what you have tried with ArrayLists

Comment: please show your code :)

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a for-each loop and call `.getWidth()` on each `Shape` instance in the list

Comment: @Janus Varmarken  Shape is the father class of the other shapes(circle, rectangle etc). I cant create a getWidth method there, should I create an interface to all the classes with getWidth method?
I also cant create an instance of width in the Shape class, because not all shapes have it(in Circle class I dont use width, I use radius, so it will be incorrect to do it

Comment: @Janus Varmarken I solved it with creating a new method as an abstract instance in Shape class and implementing it in the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you can use streams

```
int allShapeWidths = list.stream().mapToInt(Shape::getWidth).sum();
```

Assuming there is a getWidth() method in Shape (is Shape an interface?)

Comment: no Shape is the father class of the other shapes(circle, rectangle etc). I cant create a getWidth method there, should I create an interface to all the classes with getWidth method?

Comment: I also cant create an instance of width in the Shape class, because not all shapes have it(in Circle class I dont use width so it will be incorrect to do it)

Comment: I solved it with creating a new method as an abstract instance in Shape class and implementing it in the other classes.